# WPF TwoWay Binding Not Working on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox

I have a simple example using a TextBox and TextBlock in WPF to demonstrate two-way binding, but so far it's not working.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=p_firstValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=p_secondValue}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And here's the C#:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new Controller();
        }
    }

    internal class Controller : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private int firstValue = 0;
        public int p_firstValue
        {
            get { return firstValue; }
            set
            {
                firstValue = value;
                SetSecondValue();
            }
        }

        private int secondValue;
        public int p_secondValue
        {
            get { return secondValue; }
            set { secondValue = value; }
        }

        public void SetSecondValue()
        {
            p_secondValue = firstValue * 2;
            RaisePropertyChanged("p_secondValue");
        }

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
```

My expectation is that the second value will visually changed as I type, but it's not working with the binding alone.

I got a *version* of this working by binding the TextBox's `TextChanged` to a handler function that parses the string to make sure it's numeric and then calls `SetSecondValue()` in the controller directly.

I don't feel like I should *have* to do all that extra work, though, since `Mode=TwoWay` is set.  What am I missing here?

Comment: [Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Answer (score -1):

I needed to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to my xaml binding.  Now it works.